# How to get "this" from generic in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I would like to create a default function for interface with generic attribute and for this, I need to get "this" value as the value of T class, not of Responsable< T >.

```
interface Responsable<T> {
    fun toResponseModel(assembler: RepresentationModelAssembler<T, EntityModel<T>>): EntityModel<T> {
        return assembler.toModel(this)
    }
}
```

Actually, "this" is an instance of Responsabe. What should I do to pass the parameter of T class?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Could you show example usages of the interface and method you're trying to declare?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to declare a function that works on any `T` that is also a `Responsable<T>`, it might be better to declare it as an extension function on such `T`s:

```kotlin
interface Responsable<T>

fun <T : Responsable<T>> T.toResponseModel(assembler: RepresentationModelAssembler<T, EntityModel<T>>): EntityModel<T> {
    return assembler.toModel(this)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've resolved this

```
interface Responsable<T> {
    fun toResponseModel(assembler: RepresentationModelAssembler<T, EntityModel<T>>): EntityModel<T> {
        return assembler.toModel(this as T)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is quite unsafe, there is no reason for `Responsable<T>` to also be a `T`. What if you declare `class Dog : Responsable<Cat>` ?

Comment: So how to do it safely? I mean how to declare that class implementing that interface has to be also T?

Comment: I suggested a solution in my answer. I believe it does what you want, but feel free to comment if it doesn't solve your problem